# auto-launch addin when excel opens with query params

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We have a website with excel documents attached to each and every row. On click of the attachment link we need to download & auto launch excel with office-js addin sideloaded by sending some properties (session context) from the main website to the addin website.

Basically the idea is to re-use the session of the main website and pass it on to the addin website when the excel addin opens. Please let me know if this is possible in excel web addin. Or any other alternate way to achieve this to send some information to the add-in website from the document source website. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's indeed possible.  You can auto-generate the document on the fly (e.g., using OpenXML server-side), embedding any settings, and also optionally making the taskpane auto-open.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Comment: Thanks Michael. For setting session context, you are asking to check & set it @ OpenXml server side and use it in the add-in at the time of opening the document. Pls let me know.

Comment: Correct, you would embed the document with the particular settings.  The article, or at least a sample linked from the article, has an example

Comment: Is it possible to tag the document at client side itself? I could see some OOXML SDK js implementations, is it possible?

Comment: @VikasKrishnan, I have left the Office Extensibility space some time ago. I recommend you ask a new question to get it on the team's radar... Best of luck!